# Taking a list of items and displaying a value from each item as a string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a function that takes a list of items i.e. [item_1, item_2] etc.

Each item itself is a dictionary on another page. i.e. item_1 {key: value, etc}
I want to display the value of the key (called "name") for each item in the list.

For example if the input to the function, list_of_items() is [item_1, item_2]

Should return 'name of item 1, name of item 2' as a string separated by commas.

```
new_list = []
for i in items:
    new_list.append(i["name"])

return str(new_list).strip('[]')
```

This code returns "'name of item 1', 'name of item 2'" and it is the closest I have gotten.

How can I return the string I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the list of strings into a single string. Example -

```
new_list = []
for i in items:
    new_list.append(i["name"])

return ','.join(new_list)
```

This can be simplified using the below list comprehension -

```
return ','.join([i['name'] for i in items])
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> items = [{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'},{'name':'c'}]
>>> ','.join([i['name'] for i in items])
'a,b,c'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @AnandSKumar is perfect. In addition, note that you don't actually have a function in the code that you provided. A function in python begins with the `def` statement. So copying some code from @AnandSKumar, you have the following function:

```
def dictsName2str ( listOfDicts ) :
    return ','.join([i['name'] for i in listOfDicts])
```

Then you can call your function with the following code:

```
>>> items = [{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'},{'name':'c'}]
>>> myStr = dictsName2str( items )
```